# Missing dependencies installing Lua Development Tools IDE Eclipse on Linux CentOS 7

Tags: eclipse, lua, ide, torch

I would like to use Eclipse for my Torch/Lua project, on my CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) 64-bit notebook.

I installed the latest Eclipse Luna IDE and then I tried to install the Lua Development Tools (LDT) package by following their "Existing Eclipse Installation" on the [website](http://www.eclipse.org/ldt/).

Unfortunately, after trying to install the package, Eclipse says:

```
The operation cannot be completed.  See the details.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Lua Development Tools - Remote Development Support 1.4.1.201701231614 (org.eclipse.ldt.remote.feature.group 1.4.1.201701231614)
  Missing requirement: Lua Development Tools - Core Feature 1.4.0.201608301710 (org.eclipse.ldt.core.feature.group 1.4.0.201608301710) requires 'org.eclipse.dltk.debug.ui 5.5.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Lua Development Tools - Core Feature 1.4.1.201608302152 (org.eclipse.ldt.core.feature.group 1.4.1.201608302152) requires 'org.eclipse.dltk.debug.ui 5.5.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Lua Development Tools - Core Feature 1.4.1.201701231614 (org.eclipse.ldt.core.feature.group 1.4.1.201701231614) requires 'org.eclipse.dltk.debug.ui 5.5.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Lua Development Tools 1.4.0.201608301710 (org.eclipse.ldt.feature.group 1.4.0.201608301710)
    To: org.eclipse.ldt.core.feature.group [1.4.0.201608301710]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Lua Development Tools 1.4.1.201608302152 (org.eclipse.ldt.feature.group 1.4.1.201608302152)
    To: org.eclipse.ldt.core.feature.group [1.4.1.201608302152]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Lua Development Tools 1.4.1.201701231614 (org.eclipse.ldt.feature.group 1.4.1.201701231614)
    To: org.eclipse.ldt.core.feature.group [1.4.1.201701231614]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Lua Development Tools - Remote Development Support 1.4.1.201701231614 (org.eclipse.ldt.remote.feature.group 1.4.1.201701231614)
    To: org.eclipse.ldt.feature.group 0.9.0
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse 2021-03 (4.19.0)

1. Install [DLTK](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.dltk) 5.x, such as latest [5.11](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/5.11/), from menu "Install New Software"
2. Install Lua Development Tools (mine 1.4.x), from menu "Eclipse Marketplace"

Note that DLTK is not installed in Eclipse by default, and the latest DLTK 6.x is not compatible with latest Lua Development Tools 1.4.x

Ref: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1101907/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the install wants version 5.5 or later of `org.eclipse.dltk.debug.ui` part of the Eclipse Dynamic Languages Toolkit.

It looks like version 5.5 is part of Eclipse Neon, so Luna is too old.